# JRuby, gemstash and sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite, jruby

I'm trying to run [gemstash](https://github.com/bundler/gemstash) with JRuby, but it seems to have a dependency with `sqlite3-1.3.13` which of course fails because it requires a C native extension. I've skimmed the projects issues in github and found nothing about it not beeing compatible with JRuby 9.1.14.0. Is there a workaround to the "sqlite3 won't install in JRuby" thing?

Comment: maybe, you should specify in detail what kind of issues you've managed to run into and how was your local env set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that (at least on master), the sqlite3 gem should only load under C-Ruby, while under JRuby jdbc-sqlite3 is expected to be loaded/used.

https://github.com/bundler/gemstash/blob/master/gemstash.gemspec#L48

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == "java"
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "jdbc-sqlite3", "~> 3.8"
else
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "sqlite3", "~> 1.3"
end
```

<strike>however this gems do not provide the same low-level API, so you need to make sure they have proper JDBC style DB operations in place while under JVM.</strike>

UPDATE: since they're using Sequel, all should work fine under JRuby ...